# The widgets dose not appear in android studio empty activity

Tags: android

When I was trying to make calc program I used empty activity but the buttons did not appear.

[image]

The main activity.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="280dp" />
```

The java code

```
package com.example.amr.calc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android studio Project Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: Make sure your layout is file `activity_main.xml`, or change it. In the post, you mention `main_activity.xml` as the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into the same issue. Workaround for the time being is to change your Theme in the Layout Editor to `AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

[image: highlights field to change]